# Абстрактный метод в конструкторе

Tags: c++

Насколько я понял, код ниже не компилируется, так как в c++, видимо, нельзя вызывать виртуальные функции в конструкторе

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(int parameter)
    {
        if (IsValid(parameter) == false)
            throw "Incorrect parameter";

        cout << "A Contructor" << endl;
    }

    virtual bool IsValid(int parameter) const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int parameter) : A(parameter)
    {
        cout << "B Contructor" << endl;
    }

protected:
    bool IsValid(int parameter) const override
    {
        return false;
    }  
};

int main()
{    
    A* b = new B();
    return 0;
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы параметр, передаваемый в конструктор наследников, сначала проверялся на валидность. Текущую ситуацию исправить можно очень просто: вынести `if` в конструктор каждого из наследников. Однако тогда появляется дубляж кода.
С этим ничего нельзя сделать или есть приём, который поможет мне не дублировать везде этот `if`? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормального решения нет, приходится делать через виртуальный метод `init`. Чтобы интерфейс был более-менее понятным, рекомендуется делать конструкторы `protected`, а публичным делать статический метод - фабрику, вызывающий `init`.

```
class A{
public:
   virtual ~A() = default;
   virtual bool isValid() const = 0;
   
protected:
   // Не обязательно делать init виртуальным, или можно сделать невиртуальным, и внутри вызывать какой-нибудь initImpl - зависит от потребностей. 
   virtual void init() { 
      if(!isValid()) throw;
   }
}
class B: public A{
   bool isValid_;
public:
   B() = delete; // Конструктор по умолчанию смысла не имеет
   bool isValid() const override{ return isValid_; }

   // Скорее всего нужно создавать сразу unique_ptr<B> , но это уже от использования зависит
   static B create(bool isValid) {
      B ret{isValid};
      ret.init();
      return ret;
   }
protected:  
   // Создавать можно только через create, 
   // но потенциальные наследники должны иметь доступ к конструктору
   explicit B(bool isValid): isValid_(isValid){}

   // В новых версиях стандарта не обязателен, в C++14, если не ошибаюсь,
   // для возврата экземпляра класса из функции нужен конструктор копирования или перемещения, 
   // хотя на деле использоваться он не будет из-за return value optimisation.
   B(B&&) = default; 

   void init() override{
     A::init(); 
     cout << "B::init()\n";
   }
}
```